# PCA and orange software

Tags: pca, normalization, orange

I am analyzing if 15 books can be grouped according to 6 variables (of the 15 books, 2 are written by an author, 6 by an other one, and 7 by an other one).
I counted the number of occurrences of the variables and I calculated the percentage. Then I used Orange software to use PCA. I uploaded the file. selected the columns and row. And when it comes to PCA the program asks me if I want to normalize the data or not, but I am not sure about that because I have already calculated the percentage - is normalize different from calculating the percentage? Moreover, below the normalize button it asks me to show only:... and I have to choose a number between 0 and 100 but I do not really know what it is.

Could you help me understand what I should do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize data but you dont have to. If you dont normalize your data bigger range data will have higher effect on the model.

Just draw a box plot to compare the ranges of your data. If they have different ranges (like 100->200 and 1->10) you should definitely normalize your data. (Like mean normalization)